# create view subquery in Aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle, view, aggregate

I want create a summary view just like

```
create view XXX as (
   select 
     a,
     sum(select b from XX where c = ? ) 
  from 
    .....
)
```

I want some condition in `sum(...)` but  it depends on outside parameter eg

```
select * from XXX where c = ?
```

I want the condition `c = ?` in the second sql can send into view  just like use this sql

```
   select 
     a,
     sum(select b from XX where c = ? ) 
  from 
    ...
  where c = ?
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can't create view with parameter. You can create function with parameters which fill return you a REF CURSOR, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It is simply not possible to define a view such that you have a placeholder for the criteria which is going to be applied later on the view.

That leaves you with about two options:

1. Try to get all relevant information from the data. E.g. if you want to react on whether a certain user is being selected or not you could count distinct users in your data set:

`case when count(distinct user) over () = 1 then (select ...) else (select ...) end`

2. Write a PL/SQL pipelined function and use that instead of a view:

`select * from table( my_pipelined_function(in_user => null) )`